# Would Guardian's Counter work while flanking?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Dragon Magazine 399, under "Character Themes", introduces a power named "Guardian's Counter." This power is described as follows:

> You and the ally shift up to 2 squares as a free action, 
>   swapping positions. You become the target of the triggering 
>   attack, in place of the ally. After the attack is resolved, you 
>   can make a basic attack against the attacker.

It is triggered by:

> An ally within 2 squares of you is attacked and you are 
>   not included in the attack

If the allies are in a flanking position around a mob like so:

```
F * *
* M *
* * C
```

where F = fighter, M = mob, and C = cleric, can the cleric use this power to take damage in place of the fighter?

**Edit:**
The mob being flanked did not initiate the attack. Another mob initiated the attack some squares away as a ranged attack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say no

The attack power does allow you to shift 2 square 
but you cannot move through an enemies square
unless you have a feat / class feature that allows you to specifically do so
The cleric needs to be in the fighters square
(RAW)

the intention of the power is that the Cleric would leap in the way of the blow, as a story idea, (as a DM) you could allow it to work.